# Keep CSS background properties when setting an inline background-image

Tags: css, properties, background

I'm trying to figure out why when setting an inline background-image all other background properties are not working.

External CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,.8)), url("http://lorempixel.com/1400/900/");
```

Result: 
[image]

But when an inline background-image is added the gradient property seems to be ignored.

Inline CSS

```
<div class="intro-img" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1400/900/')">
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're actually overriding your background property with your

```
background-image: url('XXX')
```

You could fix it by also adding your gradient to your inline style

Another solution would be using another element / pseudo element to handle your gradient

```css
#test, #test2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

.is-overlayed {
position: relative
}
.is-overlayed::after {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.6), rgba(0,0,0,.6));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.text {
  color: #fff;

}
.above-overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class='is-overlayed' style='background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/1400/900/")'>
<p class='text above-overlay'>ABOVE OVERLAY</p>
<p class='text under-overlay'>UNDER OVERLAY</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using another pseudo element seems like a nice workaround, but If there is text on top of the image it applies to that too.